# Prove that $\overline {A \times B}$ = $\bar A \times \bar B$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be closed subsets of the topological spaces $(X_1, T_1)$ and $(X_2, T_2)$ respectively. Prove that $\overline{A\times B}$ = $\bar A \times \bar B$.

Suppose $(x,y)\in \bar{A} \times \bar{B}$.

Let $V$ be an open set with $(x,y)$ in $\bar{A} \times \bar{B}$.
Then  $V$ contains a subset $S\times T$ with $x\in{S}$ and $S$ is open in $X_1$ and $y\in{T}$ and $T$ open in $X_2$. But $S$ meets $A$ (since $x\in{\bar{A}}$) and $T$ meets $B$. So $S\times T$$\Rightarrow V$ meet $A\times B$ so $(x,y) \in \overline{A\times B}$.

Suppose $(x,y) \in \overline{A\times B}$. Then every open set with ($x,y$) of the form $S\times T$ meets $A\times B$. Hence, every open set $S$ containing $x$ meets $A$ and every open set $T$ containing $y$ meets $B$.

$\therefore x\in{\bar{A}}$ and $y\in{\bar{B}}$, so $(x,y)\in \bar{A}\times \bar{B}$

$\therefore \overline{A\times B} = \bar{A}\times \bar{B}$

This is what I have but I don't think I have it completely right so would like to have it checked, please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. In fact you don't even need $A$ and $B$ to be closed. Your proof works for **arbitrary** subsets $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
$A\subset\bar{A}\subset A$ for a closed set $A$.

This would simplify the proof drastically.

Comment: No one can dispute the truth of what you say about closed sets, but the OP asks for a critique of their proof attempt.  Perhaps you can add material to your Answer that more explicitly addresses that request.